My pug code is treated as jsx for no reason
Today a problem appeared.  I assume something was updated in vscode, vue, or pug plugins.  My syntax highlighting is destroyed in one file because something thinks that my javascript file is jsx.  I saw something in my package.json about jsx and I removed it with no improvement.  My file is a vue single-page-component with .vue suffix that uses pug.  My other plain javascript files have no problem.  The first few lines in the file are ...
<template lang="pug">  
#all(style=\`width:100%; height:95dvh; box-sizing: border-box;  

The error that appears in my problem list is JSX expressions must have one parent element..
This puts red underlines in every line of my file.  The file still works but it is hard as hell to edit with that ugliness. I tried turning off all syntax checking by putting this in settings.json but the red lines are still there ...
  "files.associations": {
    "*.*": "plaintext"
  }

My entire package.json is ...
{
"name": "tv-series-client",
"version": "0.1.0",
"private": true,
"scripts": {
"serve-vite": "vite",
"build-vite": "vite build --base=/shows/",
"preview-vite": "vite preview"
},
"dependencies": {
"@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.36",
"@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^5.15.4",
"@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.4",
"@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome": "^3.0.0-5",
"axios": "^0.24.0",
"core-js": "^3.6.5",
"lodash": "^4.17.21",
"sweetalert2": "^11.14.5",
"vue": "^3.0.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@originjs/vite-plugin-commonjs": "^1.0.1",
"@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^2.3.2",
"@vitejs/plugin-vue-jsx": "^1.3.2",
"@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0",
"babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
"eslint": "^6.7.2",
"eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.0.0",
"pug": "^3.0.2",
"pug-plain-loader": "^1.1.0",
"vite": "^2.7.2",
"vite-plugin-env-compatible": "^1.1.1",
"vite-plugin-html": "2.1.1"
},
"eslintConfig": {
"root": true,
"env": {
"node": true
},
"extends": [
"plugin:vue/vue3-essential",
"eslint:recommended"
],
"parserOptions": {
"parser": "babel-eslint"
},
"rules": {
"no-unused-vars": "off",
"no-debugger": "off",
"no-empty": "off"
}
},
"browserslist": [
"> 1%",
"last 2 versions",
"not dead"
]
}

Any help would be appreciated.

Does the problem appear only in editor and not on build? Then it's VSC problem, it's better for the question to emphasize this. And then this "I assume something was updated in vscode" sounds like a plausible explanation. There are at least 2 moving parts - vsc and its vue plugin, also ts version stackoverflow.com/questions/39668731 can affect the way it works even if you don't use ts in the project. It's unknown what the versions are. I'd start solving this by checking how this works in the latest vsc portable in parallel with current vsc installation

I'm ebarrased to say that I fixed this and I don't know how.  I had a bad day with a number of vscode problems.  I reinstalled vsc and plugins and fixed everything.

Good you sorted this out. This correlates with my own experience with vsc
